# How to get the json data use Axios in my Vue.js project

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

I have a `server_config.json` in my project's `/src/static/js` directory.

```
{
  "ApiUrl":"http://localhost:8000"
}
```

in my `main.js`, I want to use Axios to get the data:

```
Vue.prototype.getConfigJson = function () {

  this.$http.get("/static/js/server_config.json").then((response)=> {

    Vue.prototype.ApiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000';
  }).catch((response)=> {

    if (response == null) {
      Vue.prototype.ApiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000';

    }
  });
}
```

in my `App.vue` I emit the function:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted: function () {
      this.getConfigJson();
    }
  }
</script>
```

but I can not get the json data, I will catch this:

```
catch((response)=> {}
```

the `response` is `undefined`.

Comment: You should check your browser dev tool's network panel to have insight on the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use axios in any Vue component or .js file (main.js, store.js and etc.) by:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.get('www').then(res => {// your code})
```

and for Vue files sure you need do it inside  tag:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
      mounted() {
        axios.get('www').then(res => {// your code})
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: how do you mean the `'www'`?

Comment: localhost:8000/static/js/server_config.json